# Make flippy pager appear in full content view

Tags: 7, paging

I love the simplicity of the Flippy pager, and it works exactly as advertised until I display the node it's supposed to appear on in a view. Basically, I want the latest node of a specific content type to appear as the front page. Okay, I can use a view with the full content style and number of results set to 1. That works, but the pager (generated by Flippy) is missing. This is a webcomic site, so it is critical that the pager appear. Is there any way to make the pager appear exactly as it does if I navigate to the actual node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this. I am also going to post the answer to drupal.org. I modified flippy.module using the following changes:

```
--- flippy.module.orig  2013-03-10 13:14:53.000000000 -0500
+++ flippy.module       2013-03-10 13:19:09.000000000 -0500
@@ -233,6 +233,8 @@
   // for getting node type
   if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
     $vars['node'] = $node;
+  } else {
+    $vars['node'] = node_load($vars['list']['current']['nid']);
   }

   $label_type = variable_get('flippy_label_type_' . $vars['node']->type, NULL);
@@ -315,7 +317,8 @@
   if (!is_object($node)) {
     return FALSE;
   }
-  return node_is_page($node) && variable_get('flippy_'. $node->type, NULL);
+  //return node_is_page($node) && variable_get('flippy_'. $node->type, NULL);
+  return variable_get('flippy_'. $node->type, NULL);
  }

 /**
```

Notes: This should be an option selectable in the module UI. Probably not everyone wants the pager in a view. Also, I'm not sure why `menu_get_object()` is really needed at all, since the current node is already available in `$vars['list']['current']['nid']`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wish this was possible without editing the module. Also, the module has changed since this answer was posted, but the fix still works, you just have to search for the right place to put it.